# How can I stop div/elements overlapping in this case?

Tags: html, css, overlap

Currently, my divs/elements overlap each other. How can I fix it? If you found more issues in my code let me know. I try with position and other things (eg. margin) but don't work for me or I don't know how to do it. Maybe someone also can help me how to make this menu sticky while scrolling down.

Thanks for your help!

```css
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #282A2E;
    font-family: 'Fira Code', monospace;

}

menu {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 200px);
    grid-gap: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;



}

.menu__item {
    border: 3px dotted white;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;

}


.menu__item a {
    text-decoration: none !important;

    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;




}

#whoami #skills #projects {
    padding-bottom: 50px;

}



.description__text {
    border: 3px dotted#282A2E;
    width: 500px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 200px;
    height: 399px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
}

.description__text h1 {

    color: #282A2E;
    font-size: 50px;

}

.description__text p {

    color: #282A2E;
}

.section__header h1 {
    width: auto;
    height: 50px;
    border: 3px dotted#282A2E;
    background-color: white;
    display: block;
    margin-top: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fira+Code:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="hereFontAwesome" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <menu>

            <div class="menu__item">
                <a href="#whoami">whoami</a>
            </div>
            <div class="menu__item">
                <a href="#skills">skills</a>
            </div>
            <div class="menu__item">
                <a href="#projects">projects</a>
            </div>
            <div class="menu__item">
                <a href="contact">contact</a>
            </div>

        </menu>

        <section id="whoami">

            <img src="./images/shahadat-rahman-BfrQnKBulYQ-unsplash.jpg"
                style="border: 2px solid white; float: right; margin-right: 200px; ">
            <article class="description__text">
                <h1>Who am I?</h1>
                <p>TEST!</p>
                <p>TEST</p>
                <p>TEST</p>
                <p>TEST</p>

            </article>
        </section>
        <section id="skills">
            <div class="section__header">
                <h1>
                    My skills
                </h1>
            </div>
            <article style="margin-top: 100px;">
                <div style="color: white;display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 500px); gap:50px;
            text-align: center; justify-content:center">
                    <i class="fab fa-html5 fa-5x"></i>
                    <i class="fab fa-css3-alt fa-5x"></i>
                    <i class="fab fa-sass fa-5x"></i>
                    <i class="fab fa-js-square fa-5x"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-database fa-5x"></i>
                    <i class="fab fa-git fa-5x"></i>

                </div>
                <p style="color: white; text-align: center; margin-top: 100px;">TEXT </p>
            </article>

        </section id="projects">
        <div class="section__header">

            <h1>My projects</h1>
        </div>
        </section>


    </div>
    <script src="./scripts/script.js" async defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason for the overlapping elements is because you're floating an element (`article.description__text`) inside an element (`section#whoami`) which is not floated.

If you're using floats to layout your page, you need to use `float` on all your elements. A more modern way to layout your page would be to use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Answer (score 0):

Add a , between these `section id`

```
#whoami,
#skills,
#projects {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

and remove  `float: left;` from `.description__text` class.It will fix the overlapping issue .

https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-river-kkkps?file=/style.css

Comment: Fahad it works but how can I replace float to something which will work same as float

Comment: use margin-right: auto; inside .description__text class.It works same like float:left

Comment: I hope this will help https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-river-kkkps?file=/style.css